# Windows 10 November Update...?

Tags: windows-10, windows-update

So it's officially December now. I still have yet to receive the November Update for Windows 10 Pro at work and at home. I've been checking every day since the November Update was initially released. I know I can use the MCT, but I want to do it through Windows Updates. Any ideas as to why I'm not receiving the update?

- Defer Updates is not checked
- Give me updates for other MS products... is not checked
- Automatic updates is selected
- Many restarts have happened since it was released
- Current build is 10240

Comment: The update is still being rolled out.  If you want it sooner then you should upgrade using the Media Creation Tool.  If you prefer to use Windows Update to download and install it, even though the update process is identical, you will have to simply wait.

Comment: get the ISO and do a manual upgrade (running setup.exe from mounted ISO): http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/techbench

Comment: I got the ISO and tried to update via Media creation tool but i have the same problem as @jeremyT